# Vue JS v-if not updating data on login

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm using Vue JS for the first time, and I have a navigation bar which shows two buttons 'Login' and 'Sign Up', and a third one 'Logout' which won't show unless the user is logged in.

I wrapped these buttons inside a `<template v-if="authenticated">` and `<template v-else>` the login form and the registration form are a simple Bootstrap 4 modal

The way I'm toggling the `authenticated` variable is like this

```
    data: function() {
      return {
        authenticated: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      logout: function() {
        this.$session.destroy()
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.authenticated = this.$session.exists()
    },
```

My navigation bar is in a separate component and my login & registration forms are in a separate modals each.

```
  <template v-if="authenticated">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#" v-on:click="logout" class="nav-link">تسجيل الخروج</a>
    </li>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-target="#signup" data-toggle="modal" href="#signup">إنشاء حساب</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-target="#login" data-toggle="modal" href="#login">دخول</a>
    </li>
  </template>
```

Although when I log `authenticated` it gets changed.

Comment: As far as your code shows, you are only assigning `authenticated` once it is created. This does not react to changes you make inside your `$session`

Comment: i set it to true when a user sign's in successfully and to false when the user log's out, but i'm doing setting it to true on a component named 'login.vue' while i want the change to take an effect in 'navigation.vue' component

Answer (score 1):

I feel like this is a common issue. One possible way to force a component rerender is just to add a 'key' prop with full path value when using the component. For example:

```
<Navbar :key="$route.fullPath"></Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
  methods: {
       logout: function() {
         this.$session.destroy()
       }
  }
```

to this:

```
  methods: {
       logout: function() {
         this.$session.destroy();
         this.authenticated = false;
       }
  }
```

so that your `authenticated` variable is aware that you have logged out.  Other then that, your code should work.

Comment: i did it .. it's working on the logout function, but not on the login function, could it be because i have the login in a component and the navigation bar in another one ?

Comment: Yep, if you have code in a component that you want to set `authenticated` to true, then there are two approaches.  The standard way (but a bit more involved) is to have the component emit an event indicating that the visitor was authenticated and then have the main vue instance listen for the event and set `this.authenticated = true`.  **Or, the simpler way** is to have the component set the `authenticated` property on the main vue instance by accessing it via the var that `Vue` was assigned to. So if vue was instantiated via  `var app = new Vue( ...)` then use `app.authenticated = true;`

Comment: A lot of information .. i'm a beginner, how can i google about the second approach ? Do u know a tutorial about or could you explain a little bit please ?

Comment: I googled accessing Vue instance via global variable and found this article that may be helpful https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/accessing-vue-instance-outside-declaration. However it does depend on how you are loading Vue.

Comment: @Hasboosh, since you are a beginner I should also mention that using code on the client side to manage security is easily hacked and only suitable for toy projects.  For any project of consequence that needs security the security code must be implemented on the backend.  Also, if my answer answered your questions please accept it.